# Cant show multiple dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to display `'n'` custom dialogs in android.I created the dialog outside the while loop and set the message inside the loop.I need to show the dialog boxes with different messages based on the loop. But it shows android.view.WindowLeaked exception in the dialog.show() line. Can Anyone help me to solve my issue.

My code is like this:

```
//notif_count is the row count
if(notif_count>0)
{
 dialog = new Dialog[notif_count];
 for(ct=0;ct<notif_count;ct++)
 {
  dialog[ct] = new Dialog(this);
  dialog[ct].requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialog[ct].setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_alert);
 }

  cursor.moveToFirst();
  ct = 0;
  do
  {
     dec_name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_Handler.name));

     TextView tv_alert = (TextView)dialog[ct].findViewById(R.id.txt_alert);
     tv_alert.setText( dec_name );

     Button yes = (Button) dialog[ct].findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
     Button no = (Button) dialog[ct].findViewById(R.id.btn_no);

     yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(donateurl));
             startActivity(intent);
             ct--;
             dialog[ct].dismiss();
             cursor.close();
             sqldb.close();
             finish();
        }
     });

      no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           ct--;
           dialog[ct].dismiss();
           cursor.close();
           sqldb.close();
           finish();
        }
      });
      dialog[ct].show();
      ct ++;
     }while(cursor.moveToNext());
   }
```

Comment: When the exception show?

Comment: @NAYOSO Its showing in the show() of dialog

Comment: post logs if possible

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple dialog at the same time is not possible.

If you want to show a sequence of dialog, you can use the onclick listeners. From one dialog, open the following one. ( [dialog interface for the listeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html))
and if you want to block your program, so the user has to click on the dialog, set the dialogs not cancelable ([setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29))